# Unable to Open an Include file "Protocols.h" using C Compiler

Tags: c, compilation, header, include

I have a c Program and it was running Perfectly, but now i want to run it in Windows. So i am trying to compile the code in the Windows 7 Operating System, using Turboc3.
When i am compiling, i am getting an error "Unable to open include file Protocols.h"
But the Protocols.h file exists in the Directory. And all the directories are set perfectly in the C compiler.

From .c file it will include one .h file, and from that .h file another .h file is included.

But still i am facing the same issue, Can anyone help me out.

The header i have is like below:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
//#include <wait.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
//#include <ipc.h>
//#include <shm.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define  socklen_t      int

/* limit values */

#define MAX_TAGS                    500
#define MAX_OBJECTS                         500

#include "Protocols.h"
```

Comment: Verify if you file name is same as included and it is in same directory where your *.c file is.

Comment: If the file was edited under Linux, then `retype the file name with quotes ("") again in windows environment`

Comment: Does this ancient Turbo-C version support "long" (>8.3 characters) file names? Try renaming the file to "Protocol.h".

Answer (score 0):

If you really set the correct path in you compiler, you could try to hardcode the path like #include "/path/name.h". 
If this works, you have some issue with your compiler and maybe not set the path (the right way).
If this does not work it seems, that the file is not existing or broken in some way. In this case: Get a new version of the headerfile and make sure, that it is in the right place.